# Can I revert back to an older save of Minecraft on my 360?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

So basically, I just updated my xbox 360 minecraft game for the first time in ages. The update began but I then backed out of it, and tried to go onto one of my worlds. However, the world was entirely new, and it seemed it was the original version of the game. I then finished the update, only to find that the world I had tried was completely gone, in place of this new one. I'm really angry about this, as the world meant a lot to me, and it was just overwritten by some new crap that I didn't even want. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the old save back? I really don't care if it is complex or "unethical" to Microsoft, I just want to get my old world back. Thanks.